# How to extend a React component with composition in TypeScript without "missing properties"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here's what I'm trying:

```
const ActionLink: typeof NavLink = ({onClick, ...props}) => {
    function handleClick(ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        if(onClick) onClick(ev);
    }
    return <NavLink {...props} onClick={handleClick}/>
}
```

I don't think it's really important what `NavLink` is just that I want `ActionLink` to 'inherit' all of its properties. However, when I try doing `typeof NavLink` like that I get this error:

```
src/components/App.tsx:155:7 - error TS2739: Type '({ onClick, ...props }: ClassAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> & Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>, "media" | ... 257 more ... | "css"> & { ...; } & { ...; }) => Element' is missing the following properties from type 'StyledComponent<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>, Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>, "media" | ... 257 more ... | "css">, any>': withComponent, __emotion_styles

155 const ActionLink: typeof NavLink = ({onClick, ...props}) => {
          ~~~~~~~~~~
```

How come? How am I missing properties? Shouldn't `...props` capture all of them?

---

`NavLink` is an [emotion styled component](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled):

```
const NavLink = styled.a`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    &:hover {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
`;
NavLink.defaultProps = {href: ''};
```

Comment: I assume `NavLink` is from `react-router-dom`? In which case, it is a stateful component (as object as opposed to a function), so `typeof` won't work if you're declaring `ActionLink` as a functional component. You can use `class ActionLink extends NavLink`. But even facebook themselves discourage inheritance: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance

Comment: @Richard Sorry, it's actually a styled component: https://emotion.sh/docs/styled I'm not sure why statefulness would break though just because I've put it inside a functional component...?

Comment: @mpen Did you ever figure this out? Been researching this for a while now.

Comment: @eivindml Yeah actually. The proper way to compose other components is `const ActionLink = React.FC<React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof NavLink>> = props => { <NavLink {...props} /> }`

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it's because `withComponent` and `__emotion_styles` aren't React props, but rather they are JS props on the function itself.